# jQuery mobile image resizing after changing orientation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

Hello guys one problem ...

I use JQM 1.4 ... and i want to make a map with Image mapster  http://www.outsharked.com/ImageMapster/

the problem is the following ... when i have the phone in portrait mode everything works fine ... but when changed in landscape mode .... the image gets resized ... and when i put it back in portrait mode ... it gets eveen bigger ...

did anyone of you had any simmilar problem ?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are resizing the image using jquery, try to resize it using css media query that's more faster and stable process, use something like this in CSS:

`@media screen and (orientation:portrait) { /*CSS for portrait*/ }`

and

`@media screen and (orientation:landscape) { /*CSS for landscape*/ }`

Don't forget to use media="screen" attribute on link tag where placing css file or it won't work.

Alternatively, you can provide max-width to the image in Percentage or pixels (in case of fixed width) and height set to auto, something like this `max-width:80%; height:auto;` to avoid image stretch when screen resizes or orientation changes.

Comment: the problem is that I use image mapping ... and when the image gets resized  the coordinates are not updated so they dont match the image and so don't work ...  and everything i use ... the image still doesnt remain the  same ... everytime it gets resized ... :(

Comment: Here's something you can do. in firefox press ctrl+shift+m and you'll get mobile screen view. try changing orientation from here. When image gets resized, open firebug or browser's developer tools and put map initializer you used like this `$('#myimage').mapster({fillColor: 'ff0000',  fillOpacity: 0.3});` in console and run it.
this should recall coordinates function and set with image accordingly, if this happends, put this code in jquery image resize or orientation function

Comment: the problem is that i dont know why the image resizes over the screen limits ... I used this 
<img src="images/map.jpg"  usemap="#usa" style="max-width:100%; height:auto;">

and still doesnt work ...  and i tried in the firefox with mobile screen mode ... but no success